# Write multiple images for face recognition with opencv and python

Tags: python, opencv

I'm new in python programming and I want to detect faces in some pictures that I downloaded from google and I have in a folder. My code already recognizes faces in the pictures and uses a box/square to frame them. What I want to do is to save or write the image in the box into a different folder but with the same name that the original pictures have. Here is the code to detect faces and frame it in a box

```
import cv2
import os

faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
imgFormat = ".jpeg"
fullimgpath = "full_image/"
faceimgpath = "face_image/"
imfilelist = [os.path.join(fullimgpath, f) for f in os.listdir(fullimgpath) if f.endswith(imgFormat)]

for el in imfilelist:
    print el
   imagen = cv2.imread(el)
   gray = cv2.cvtColor(imagen, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
   faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
        gray,
        scaleFactor=1.1,
        minNeighbors=5,
        minSize=(30, 30),
        flags=cv2.cv.CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE
   )

    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(imagen, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        roi_color = imagen[y:y + h, x:x + w]


    cv2.imshow('Imagen', imagen)
    cv2.waitKey(1000)
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Ok I added this two lines of code `cv2.imwrite("face_image/%01i.jpg" % cpt, roi_color)` and `cpt += 1` and now I have the face from the box in another folder but I put the name manually there's a way to do take the name from the original picture and put in the new image?

Comment: The full path of the image is being stored in the `el` variables of for loop, you need to write a function to extract the image name from it. ex: if path in el is `/Users/xyz/project/sample_img.png` then you may use `el.split("/")[-1]` to extract the file name from full path.